# Relationship between MLE and Pitman–Koopman–Darmois Theorem

Tags: maximum-likelihood, exponential-family

Is there a relationship between the applicability of Maximum Likelihood Estimation and Pitman-Koopman-Darmois Theorem?

I mean if the dimensionality of the sufficient statistics depend on the sample size, does this mean MLE cannot be applied? Clearly MLE can be applied to say estimating parameters of Student-t distribution, which is not from exponential family.

So what is the connection, if there is any?

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not.

Consider the negative binomial distribution with both parameters unknown.  Its (minimal but not complete) sufficient statistic is the (vector of) order statistics (http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002461064&physid=PHYS_0353 ; note, you have to go to the page after the book review to see the paper with the proof.)  Evidently the dimensionality of this statistic depends on the sample size and is unbounded as the sample size goes to infinity.   Yet a maximum likelihood estimator exists.

When we actually use an estimator / calculate an estimate, we are dealing with a fixed sample.  At that point, the dimensionality of the sufficient statistic is fixed as well.  It's certainly *nicer* when we have a sufficient statistic of fixed dimension as the sample size increases, but by no means essential.

Comment: I always thought that estimators for the parameters of a distribution qualified as sufficient statistics. Negative binomial has two parameters. Does this mean if I have an estimator for each parameter, they will not be jointly sufficient?

Comment: Nope!  In fact, Pitman-Koopman-Darmois provides the basis for a counterexample!  P-K-D says that only for exponential family distributions is the minimal sufficient statistic of bounded dimension as the sample size increases, but the Negative Binomial is not a member of the exponential family.  Therefore, the sufficient statistic is not of bounded dimension as the sample size increases.  However, since the N.B. only has two parameters regardless of sample size, and "two" is definitely bounded, it cannot be that the parameter estimates are jointly sufficient.

Comment: So what does this tell us? If I am not in exponential family I shouldn't be using the likelihood even if I know the correct specification and instead opt for a mixture model that will grow in size in order to have better inference?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the MLE for a non-exponential family distribution, it's not clear to me why you would think so.  Just because the distribution is not a member of the exponential family doesn't mean the MLE doesn't have all the nice asymptotic properties.  It only means you won't be able to calculate the MLE using only a small (bounded) number of sufficient statistics.  Note that in order to calculate those sufficient statistics, you'll still need the whole sample, so it's not like a bounded number of sufficient statistics is any great guarantor of computational efficiency.

Comment: When you say I won't be able to calculate MLE, what exactly do you mean? It is a numerical optimization after all. I will happily grant the bounty, I just need a little bit further intution.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you wouldn't be able to calculate the MLE, I meant that you wouldn't be able to calculate it *with a bounded number of sufficient statistics*.  I should have emphasized that this is because there *isn't* a bounded number of sufficient statistics (given the assumption that the dist'n isn't a member of the exponential family), not because you can't do the calculation with however many sufficient statistics you have (in some cases equal to the sample size).  Sorry for the lack of clarity!

Comment: (+1) NB There's a qualification in the PKD theorem - it applies only for families of distributions where the parameter doesn't determine the support. So the sample maximum is sufficient for $\theta$ in the family of uniform distributions $\mathcal{U}(0,\theta)$.

Comment: I still don't get it. What you are saying is I can calculate MLE with the samples I have, and I will have the parameter estimates. How is it different from plugging those parameter estimates to the likelihood. Basically can you compare the negative binomial example with the gaussian estimation? MLE steps are the same after all.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now.  Are you wondering why the MLE parameter estimates aren't themselves sufficient statistics?  If that's it, I'll put together something and add it to the answer above later on today.

Comment: Yes. Because it seems to open the door to Rao-Blackwell even for the Bayesian case.